# separate css for mozilla 3.5 and 3.0.11

Tags: css, firefox

Is their any option for calling separate css for mozilla 3.5 and 3.0.11

Answer (score 3):

You can analyze the user agent in a server-side scripting language and produce different output, specifying different stylesheets, for those browsers.

If you're meaning to ask whether you can use conditional comments for the purpose, no, you can't; conditional comments are an IE thing.

Comment: This might work (but it might just return 'ff3' regardless of point version) http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/